# How to Calculate the following integration?

Tags: definite-integrals, interpolation, bessel-functions

I need to calculate the following integration.

$$\int_0^\infty \!\,xe^{-tx^2}\, j_\alpha ( u_1 x)j_{\alpha }(u_2 x)dx$$

where
$j_\alpha ( u_1 x)$ and $j_{\alpha }(u_2 x)$ are Bessel functions of the first kind of an integer order $\alpha$.

Comment: What are $u_1$ and $u_2$? Also, the lowercase "j" is usually reserved for [spherical Bessel functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html). Usually we use a capital "J" for regular Bessel functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity 10.22.67 on [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22) says that
$$\int_0^\infty x\exp(-p^2x^2)J_{\nu}(ax)J_\nu(bx)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2p^2}\exp\left(-\frac{a^2+b^2}{4p^2}\right)I_\nu\left(\frac{ab}{2p^2}\right)$$
With $I_\nu$ being the [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) of order $\nu$. Plug in $p=\sqrt{t}$ for your answer.